# How to imitate OnBackPressed Xamarin Test Cloud?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin-test-cloud

Now I am testing my app using REPL and need to imitate tap on BackButton of Android device.
`app.Tap(c=>c.Marked("sendBN"));`
It is very simple to work with id of the button but I need exactly tap to Back button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just call [`app.Back()`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp.Back()/) to simulate the user pressing the hardware or software back key.